# Running the response of a jQuery .Ajax call (which is a string from a PHP file) as a javascript function

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am calling a php function in a javascript file via .ajax().

I have

```
$.ajax({
   url: templateDir + 'functions.php',
   async : false,
   data: "function=images",
   success: function (response) {
     alert(response);
   }
});
```

if `response` comes back as the *string* `someObject.someMethod();`, I want that string to be parsed and run. I can console.log or alert it, but I can't conceptualize how to have the string that is returned run.

I am new to jquery and ajax if you can't tell.

Comment: `$('#results_div').html('Response: ' + response['x']);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `eval`:

```
success: function (response) {
    eval(response);
}
```

Comment: Just as a note, make sure you 100% trust the source of your response to not send you anything malicious here.

Comment: @ginman Since AJAX has to stay within your own domain, it shouldn't be too hard to know if it's trustworthy.